# Testando jogos da mega sena

Tags: python-3.x

Meu professor pediu que eu gerasse um gerador de aposta da mega sena. Eu fiz, e modéstia parte ficou bem legal:

```
from time import sleep
from random import sample
palpite = list()
a = []
print('='*40)
print('=========PALPITES DA MEGA SENA==========')
print('='*40)
print()
sleep(0.1)
c = []
cont = 0
for i in range(1,61):
    c.append(i)
pergunta = int(input('\033[35mQuantos palpites deseja processar? '))
for j in range(0, pergunta):
    palpite.append(sample(c,6))

print()
palpite.sort()
sleep(1)
print('=-'*30)
print('#'*35)
print(f'sortendo {pergunta} numeros')
print('#'*35)
print('=-'*30)
print()
sleep(1.5)
for d in palpite:
    d.sort()
    cont += 1
    sleep(1)
    print(f'{cont}º Jogo = {d}')
sleep(1.5)
print()
print('-='*30)
print('\033[1;32m         >>>>> BOA SORTE <<<<<<   ')
print('Fim')
print('\033[31m^'*45)
```

Mas aí me veio uma pergunta: sou jogador até que assíduo da mega sena (pelo menos 1 vez por semana faço uma aposta). Será que é realmente possível ganhar? 
Aí eu criei um programa pra testar:

```
from random import sample
numero1 = []
numero2 = []
jogo1 = []
jogo2 = []
for n1 in range(1,61):
    numero1.append(n1)
for n2 in range(1,61):
    numero2.append(n2)
while True:
    jogo1.append(sample(numero1,6))
    jogo2.append(sample(numero2,6))
    for m in jogo1:
        m.sort()
    for z in jogo2:
        z.sort()
    if m == z:
        print(m)
        print(z)
        break
print('fim')
```

Mas não deu nada. Não deu erro, parece que ficou rodando, mas não tenho certeza. Esperei uns 5 minutos, e nada. Será que é realmente impossível, ou meu programa está simplesmente errado?

Estou usando o PyCharm.

Comment: por algum motivo, ficou extremamente bagunçado essa pergunta. Não sei o que houve, já que quando eu esta escrevendo ficou bem formatadinho

Comment: Sendo um jogador assíduo, você deve saber que a probabilidade de vender é extremamente pequena, entrei é normal que demore até que dois sorteios sejam iguais.

Comment: Bem vindo ao Stack Overflow, Douglas! Eu vi que você adicionou perguntas novas a esta, já respondida - gostaria de sugerir que você marcasse a resposta abaixo como aceita, clicando na seta, ou se você tiver alguma dúvida secundária, que faça um comentário/peça esclarecimento; com relação às suas novas questões, por favor crie uma pergunta nova, tentando apresentar um problema por vez - o intuito é manter o site organizado, e que outros usuários possam utilizar a sua questão e respostas para aprenderem também! :)

Comment: Eu tomei a liberdade de reverter sua edição - você pode clicar no link [editada...](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/324070/revisions) para rever o texto que você havia escrito, caso queira reaproveitar para uma nova pergunta - obrigado pela compreensão!

Comment: Blogueira, eu li seu comentário e agradeço profundamente pelas correções. Muito obrigado, e bela apresentação no seu perfil. Digna de aprovação pela faculdade de Sirius. NÃO ENTRE EM PÂNICO!!!. Eu quero marca essa resposta como aceita. Você me pediu pra clicar na seta...Que seta?

Comment: Na resposta, no canto superior esquerdo tem uma seta pra cima `upvote`, os votos que foram dados (no momento 5), uma seta pra baixo `downvote` e embaixo um check mark `✓` - clique nele; para que pessoas recebam notificação do seu comentário aqui, escreva o nome delas com um @ antes, por exemplo: @Blogueira

Answer (score 6):

Existem [50.063.860 possibilidades](https://brasilescola.uol.com.br/matematica/chances-ganhar-na-mega-sena.htm) de resultados nesse jogo de 6 números. A chance de sair uma combinação `[a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6]` esperada é de `1/50.063.860 = 0,00000002` que corresponde a `0,000002%`. Ou seja, a cada 50.063.860 jogos, é esperado que você ganhe 1.

Modifiquei o seu código de teste um pouco (guardar todos os valores sorteados e percorrer todos com um for e .sort() não me parece uma boa ideia):

```
from random import sample
import time

numero1 = []
for n1 in range(1,61):
    numero1.append(n1)

tentativas = 0
start = time.time()
while True:
    tentativas += 1
    if tentativas % 500000 == 0:
        print('Tentativas:', tentativas, end = ' | ')
        print('Tempo:', time.time()-start)
    m = sample(numero1, k=6)
    m.sort()
    z = sample(numero1, k=6)
    z.sort()
    if m == z:
        print('Tentativas:', tentativas)
        print('Tempo:', time.time()-start)
        print(m)
        print(z)
        break
print('fim')
```

Rodei ele algumas vezes e obtive os resultados:

Amostra 1:

```
...
Tentativas: 89500000 | Tempo: 1628.135265827179
Tentativas: 90000000 | Tempo: 1637.143269777298
Tentativas: 90500000 | Tempo: 1645.9052894115448
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Amostra 2:

```
...
Tentativas: 29500000 | Tempo: 546.6875867843628
Tentativas: 30000000 | Tempo: 556.0576255321503
Tentativas: 30500000 | Tempo: 565.2926483154297
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Amostra 3:

```
Tentativas: 500000 | Tempo: 9.574995756149292
Tentativas: 1000000 | Tempo: 18.5190167427063
Tentativas: 1009879
Tempo: 18.727997303009033
[10, 13, 28, 37, 49, 56]
[10, 13, 28, 37, 49, 56]
fim
```

Agora, quando eu mudo z para `z = [1,2,3,4,5,6]`:

Amostra 1:

```
...
Tentativas: 10000000 | Tempo: 94.66205024719238
Tentativas: 10500000 | Tempo: 99.3870267868042
Tentativas: 10634304
Tempo: 100.61703157424927
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
fim
```

Amostra 2:

```
...
Tentativas: 40000000 | Tempo: 381.7722237110138
Tentativas: 40500000 | Tempo: 386.4262237548828
Tentativas: 40534342
Tempo: 386.7422297000885
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
fim
```

Moral da história: seu código não está errado e não é impossível ganhar, assumindo que o jogo seja aleatório.

Comment: Caraca!!! eu sabia que era difícil ganhar na mega, mas depois que voce usa lógica? caraca. é assustador...

Comment: Estou realmente assustado... vou postar isso no forum Curso e video e marcar o Guanabara.... To muito assustado. É quase impossível alguém ganhar. Quase.

Comment: Obrigado pela medalha AlexCiuffa